# Is it possible to do Geosearch API using google datastore (GAE) and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, geolocation, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

I have a set of lat/longs stored in datastore db and I want to use Nodejs and Google datastore to return the result of shops surrounding me in desc order based on the distance.

i.e. I have location and I want to retrieve all the shops saved in the DB within 10km.

Comment: google for the python implementation of datastore geolocation library. you would need to copy the algorithm for node. also gae search api suports geo natively but thats not datastore.

Comment: What do you mean by gae search api supports geo natively but not datastore? I think that gae is used to extract data from google datastore.

Comment: exactly that :) appengine search api supports querying nearby spacial points, datastore does not but there is at least one library (in python) that implements geosearch in datastore. However, I now see that google now has alpha geospatial support in datastore https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch

Comment: google also shows many good answers with a trivial search like https://www.google.com/webhp?q=google%20datastore%20geospatial, try a few and let us know what went wrong.